# How to consolidate multiple rows of data entries (based on email) in a single row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How do I consolidate multiple data rows (per email) from Sheet 1:

[image: Sheet1]

into a single row on Sheet 2:

[image: Sheet2]

Here's the [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c2RsxsRXDrJ9BKQs7-UWXzJdLdr3TAWAq1e_ifMAH6k/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

In Sheet2 in A1:

```
=unique(Sheet1!A:A)
```

In B3 and copied across and down (and formatted to suit):

```
=sumif(Sheet1!$A:$A,$A3,Sheet1!B:B)
```

Add headings to suit.